# How do I fix this infinite while loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm making this program to be able to calculate factorials. I need it to say a sentence if they input a value over 20 but I have created and infinite loop. My line that says

```
System.out.print ("ERROR: The result is inaccurate because the number was    too large for the data type");}
```

Is an infinite loop. I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.  I have tried moving the placement of things but I can't figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class FactoralApp
{
public static void main(String[] arge)
{

    //Welcome users the the application and get user input
    System.out.print("Welcome to the Factoral Calculator" + "\n");


    int num;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {  //set up the while loop so that users can find many factorials

    long factorial=1; //initialize variables


    System.out.print("\n" + "Enter an integer between 1 and 20: "); //promt users for input
    num = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--){  //Calculate factorial
    factorial = factorial * i;}

    while (num > 20) {
        System.out.print ("ERROR: The result is inaccurate because the number was too large for the data type");}




    // Format and display the results

    NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

    String message =
                ("\n" + "The factoral of " + num + " is " + number.format(factorial) + "." + "\n"); //create message

    System.out.println(message);  // Output the formated message

    System.out.print ("Continue (y/n): "); //promt users for input
    choice = sc.next();
    } // End While



} // End main ()



} // End Class
```

Comment: The first step in solving your problem will be to isolate your problem, meaning it's time to do some serious debugging, either with a debugger that will allow you to step through your code and analyze variables as the program progresses, or with a logger, or with a "poor man's debugger" -- a lot of println statements that expose variable state as the program progresses. Much luck!

Comment: Did you mean to use `if` instead of `while`?

Comment: What variable are you checking in your while boolean condition? Next -- are you **changing the variable anywhere within the while loop**??? If not,  if you never change num within the loop, then the while loop's boolean test result will **never** change, and the loop will never end. This isn't a programming question , but rather it's a simple logic question.

Comment: to debug , try printing out the variables so that you can see how it changes it a loop.

Comment: Thanks PM 77-1 making it an if instead fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of while, you need an if condition to check if the number entered is greater than 20.

```
if(num > 20) {  //the result cannot be stored in a long data type so alert
        System.out.print ("ERROR: The result is inaccurate because the number was too large for the data type");}

// Format and display the results

NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

String message =
            ("\n" + "The factorial of " + num + " is " + number.format(factorial) + "." + "\n"); //create message

System.out.println(message);  // Output the formatted message

System.out.print ("Continue (y/n): "); //prompt users for input
choice = sc.next();
} // End if
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to please understand working of control statements. `while` is a loop and obviously it will run until and unless condition satisfied. Below is the correct code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //Welcome users the the application and get user input
        System.out.print("Welcome to the Factoral Calculator" + "\n");


        int num;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {  //set up the while loop so that users can find many factorials

        long factorial=1; //initialize variables


        System.out.print("\n" + "Enter an integer between 1 and 20: "); //promt users for input
        num = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--){  //Calculate factorial
        factorial = factorial * i;}

        if (num > 20) {
            System.out.print ("ERROR: The result is inaccurate because the number was too large for the data type");}




        // Format and display the results

        NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

        String message =
                    ("\n" + "The factoral of " + num + " is " + number.format(factorial) + "." + "\n"); //create message

        System.out.println(message);  // Output the formated message

        System.out.print ("Continue (y/n): "); //promt users for input
        choice = sc.next();
        } // End While



}
```

Description-: Only below section of code has been updated. Now above code will print `ERROR: The result is inaccurate because the number was too large for the data type` error only one time.

```
 if (num > 20) {
            System.out.print ("ERROR: The result is inaccurate because the number was too large for the data type");}
```

If this code change doesn't meet your requirement then provide more details. How many times you want to print that error message.

Answer (score -2):

You never change the value of the `num` variable within your while loop. Since this is the variable that you're checking in the while loop's boolean condition, the **condition will never change**, and the while loop risks running forever.

Solution: update the variable **within** the loop. Use your Scanner variable, sc, just as you did *before* the loop.